# Script to compare 2 .env files then overwrite values on the default one base on another

Tags: scripting, environment-variables

I have 2 env files. One is the default one `.env` and another one is `.env.overwrite`.

I want to have a script file that when I run and specify the arguments, for examples:

```
./rebuild_env .env .env.overwrite
```

It will overwrite the values of each key in `.env` to the one in `.env.overwrite`. If some some key is not exists in `.env.overwrite` stay default. For example:

For `.env` file:

```
VALUE1=default_value1
VALUE2=default_value2
VALUE3=default_value3
```

And in `.env.overwrite` file:

```
VALUE1=new_value1
VALUE3=new_value3
```

After run that script, `.env` file will be:

```
VALUE1=new_value1
VALUE2=default_value2
VALUE3=new_value3
```

I have try to research on the internet for 3 days already and couldn't find one that suit my need. Can someone help guide me for this? I'm really thankful for your help.

Comment: Do both files only contain entries in the format `variable=value` ?

Comment: @Smock For general purpose of env file, it's just like that.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution would be to just concatinate the two files:

```
cat .env .env.overwrite > .env.new
```

Then the last updated entry will be the active one. Now we just need to remove all the double entries.

And if the order and other comments doesn't matter:

```
for variable in \
    $(cut -d= -f1 .env.overwrite .env | sort |uniq) ; 
do 
     grep ^${variable}= .env.overwrite || \
     grep ^${variable}= .env ; 
done
```

Comment: The script work for me. I just need to redirect the output to file. For example:
```sh
./build_env > .env.new
```